# How do I connect my iphone to the Glitch A-Frame code?

Tags: aframe

I'm creating an A-Frame VR code program in Glitch.com
I'm told that I can use my smartphone iPhone like a VR Device.
How do I do that from the Show mode in Glitch.com?

Comment: Please post the code that you are having trouble with.

Comment: Treat "show mode" like any other website. Type you project URL (https://<your-project-name>.glitch.me) into safari, ff, or chrome on your phone.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the show mode on your computer or whichever device you are working on. Click on the share menu directly below it and go to

```
live app
```

Copy that link (which will be a name of your choosing)
and open that on your iPhone. You will need google cardboard to access it.